# Get all functions/values in scope with template haskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

With template haskell, is there a way to list all functions in scope? Something like

```
allVarsInScope :: Q [Name]
```

What I'm trying to do with this is get a list of all imported functions beginning with test_, and run the tests automatically.

Comment: [Test.QuickCheck.All](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/QuickCheck/2.4.1.1/doc/html/Test-QuickCheck-All.html) in case your tests are QuickCheck properties.

Comment: It doesn't cross module boundaries.

Comment: For automatic test running [see HTF project](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTF). It does pretty amazing things.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, there is no such reflection capability in Template Haskell, but there are workarounds. However, before writing something like this yourself, I recommend trying the [test-framework-th](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/test-framework-th) package which already does this for HUnit tests beginning with `case_` and also for QuickCheck properties beginning with `prop_`.

Under the hood, this package uses the [language-haskell-extract](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/language-haskell-extract) package which essentially runs its own parsing pass over the module to pick out the definitions. It's a somewhat hacky solution, but it works well enough in practice. However, it does bring in a fair number of dependencies and the additional parsing pass can slow down your builds.

Comment: If I could help it, I'd rather not re-parse every module with a test at build-time.